# Setting Background Image for UITextView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview

I have managed to get my UIImageView to show behind my UITextView and it is just fine on one view but on this one, some of the text is getting highlighted and so the image doesn't show behind that text.  The highlighted text areas have white behind them instead of the image.  Any ideas?[image]

EDIT:  I got this working correctly.  I deleted and recreated the text view in IB and it looks fine now.

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Comment: I'm doing this in interface builder.

Comment: So I assume you are using the alpha setting?